# Digital Signature for ASP.NET Dynamic Binaries

Tags: asp.net, security, compilation, web-config, dynamic-compilation

Is there a way to put a digital signature on the Temporary Binaries generated as part of ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using using assemblyPostProcessorType in the compilation tag of the web.config. Basically calling SignTool.exe with certificate info post compilation.